# Azure Media Services live streaming latency

Tags: azure, rtmp, latency, azure-media-services

I have created a channel on Azure Media Services, I correctly configured it as an RTMP channel and streamed a live video with Android + FFMpeg libraries.

The problem is the client end-point latency.

I need a maximum latency ~2 seconds, but now I have about ~25 seconds!

I'm using Azure Media Player in a browser page to stream the content.

Do you know a configuration of the client/channel which can reduce the latency?

Thanks

Comment: Which library exactly did you choose to stream from Android?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed , there are few factors which affects latency.

**Total delay time**  =

- time to push video from client to server
- server processing time
- latency for delivering content from server to client.

Check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-origins/#scale_streaming_endpoints to see how you can minimize #3 mentioned above by configuring cdn and scaling streaming end units.

Given these 3 components, i don't think at this stage you will be able archive less than 2 seconds end to end delay globally from Android client to browser client.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to check latency is ffplay --fflags nobuffer rtmp:///app/stream_name

As I did in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci646LELNBY

Then if there's no latency by ffplay, it's the player that introduce latency